# Thinkpad T450s with USB and 3mm connection problems

Tags: hardware-failure, laptop-repair, repair

I have a Thinkpad T450s with two problems that may or may not be related.

Problem 1: Audio through the 3mm jack is patchy. I know it's not the headphones because they work fine on other devices. I get audio fine through the R but through the L I have to wiggle the cable to get it through. It's getting harder to get the right angle over time.

Problem 2: USBs (mice, keyboards, doesn't seem to matter what) struggle to connect. Some ports are worse than others.

Originally i thought it was just the 3mm jack breaking, and I was going to try to replace it. I assume this is feasible (a quick google shows spare parts available). The fact that both problems are happening makes me think there might be a common cause. How do I investigate further?

Answer (score 1):

The audio socket (jack) is independent of the USB. The audio jack is connected through the motherboard to the audio output circuitry.

USB is connected to the USB bus.

Method of approach:

1. Replace the Audio jack or have a local repair person do this.
2. In Device Driver, update all USB Components.

After number 2 is complete, run Lenovo System Update and update all drivers that you can.

Then run all Windows updates you can.